# Database Table custom naming convention Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table called completion_date using Eloquent. My Model name is Completion and as per laravel documentation, i should declare a (protected) table name or else Eloquent will use 'completions' as the default table name. So i did this declaration.
I'm getting problems with my Controller since i dont know which name to use to refer to my Model when i'm making the View. I'm getting an **InvalidArgumentException** that **View [completion.lsz] not found.** if i just use my model name to make the View.

Error:

**InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "View [completion.lsz] not found."**

Can someone pls help out?

Model

```
 <?php

 //Model (file name: Completion)

 class Completion extends Eloquent{
     protected $table = 'completion_date';
     public $timestamps = false;
 }
```

Controller

```
 class CompletionController extends BaseController  {

 public function index()    {
    $lsz = Completion::all();
    return View::make('completion.lsz', ['completion' => $lsz]);


   }    
 }
```

Route

```
 Route::get('/Completion', 'CompletionController@index');
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refer to my table name when i'm making the View"? The table name normally has nothing to do with your view...

Comment: Fair enough. I'm simply following a tutorial here and very green. So how would you rewrite the return statement in the the index function in Controller so that i don't get the sql error 'Table not found'?

Comment: Honestly I don't know why you get a table not found. Could you update your question with the full Error message?

Comment: I have edited the question with some updates and the Error message. I recieved the sql error because the custom table name declaration was commented out.

Comment: Ahaa!! It can't find your VIEW file. Do you have `app/views/completion/lsz.blade.php`? If not, how does your `views` structure look like?

Comment: I have **app/views/lsz/lsz.blade.php**, i think that should do, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View names in Laravel work like a path. The `.` gets converted to a `/`
That means, your view resolves to the file `app/views/completion/lsz.blade.php` (or `app/views/completion/lsz.php` without *Blade*)

So you either have to change the name of your directory in the views folder to "completion" or change the view make command to:

```
View::make('lsz.lsz', ['completion' => $lsz]);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Error message is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the view file `completion/lsz.blade.php` was not found.

It's not related to the model or database.